# Cannot Create new Group Policy Object (GPO)

Tags: powershell, group-policy, gpo, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I was tasked to create a script where I can automated the configurations of group policy objects (GPO) using PowerShell. I'm creating a new GPO using this command:

```
New-GPO -Name "foo"
```

But, whenever I try to create a new GPO, I always encounter this error:

```
New-GPO : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
At line:1 char:1
+ New-GPO -Name "foo"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-GPO], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Commands.NewGpoCommand
```

I searched for the error code behind this, and it has something to do with the authorization of access behind this. I tried many things like downloading RSAT and other applications, but still, I can't allow my user to create a new GPO. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461062.aspx) it says: "*Only domain administrators, enterprise administrators, and members of the Group Policy creator owners group can create GPOs. These users must run Windows PowerShell in an elevated state.*"

Comment: Hi, David. How can I make my user a member of the Group Policy creator owners?

Answer (score 0):

Miquel Roque.

In your Domain, your user-account needs to have any of the previously mentioned groups:
domain administrators
enterprise administrators
Group Policy creator

All groups and access is added inside "Active Directory Users and Computers"
from a manangement server or mmc console.

You also need to run Powershell elevated (Run as Administrator).